# isUpperCase/toTitleCase/isWhiteSpace issue.

Tags: java

I created a code that, when I input a string, it will check if the word(s) need to be changed to uppercase for only the first letter of each word. For example, when the string "The brown big dog!" is inputted, it'll come out as  "The Brown Big Dog!"

Here's my code

```
public String convertToTitleCase(String s) 
   {
  if (s.isEmpty())
      return "";
  else 
  {
       String word = "";
       boolean flag = false;
       char w = s.charAt(0);
       if(!Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(0)))
           w = Character.toTitleCase(s.charAt(0)); 
       word = word + w;
       if(s.length()==1)
           return word;
       for (int i = 1; i<(s.length()-1); i++)
       {
           if (!Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i)) && flag == false)
               word = word + s.charAt(i);
           if (!Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i)) && flag == true)
               flag = false;
           if (Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i)))
           {
               word = word + " ";
               w = s.charAt(i+1);
               word = word + Character.toTitleCase(w);
               flag = true;
           }
       }
       if (!Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(s.length()-2)))
            word = word + s.charAt(s.length()-1);  
       return word;
    }
```

}

It does everything I want it to from changing "g" to "G" to changing "A dog" to "A Dog" to changing "aaab bccc cddd" to "Aaab Bccc Cddd" and recognizing if it's empty.

However, my tester has found a error with it and I can not seem to figure out what it is. I was wondering if another set of eyes can check my code for any common mistakes or something that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What corner case your tester have found? Didn't he give you a unit test that proves there is an issue with your code?

Comment: @SzymonStepniak there is, but there's only 3 cases. a Green check mark indicating it passed, a black x indicating an error and a red x indicating a failure. 

I have a black x.

Comment: what if the first character is a white-space and actual sentence starts from second character, in that case it is not properly capitalised. maybe, you can trim the string for leading white-space and then perform the rest of operation. For all other inputs, your code should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You declared this

> boolean flag = false;

And then you are checking the value of a boolean variable in java as

> flag == false

Try

> (!flag)

Also, has your tester shared his test case that failed or are you supposed to figure that out by yourself?

Comment: This will not make any difference.

Comment: its might not. But i wouldn't recommend using == for boolean check, as its redundant now.

Comment: You have a point there. Only 3 out comes, green check mark, back x and red x, so yeah I have to figure out the problem myself. The problem is I tried  many situations and it comes out as it should.  I'm not too sure wht other situations I'm missing.

Comment: I tried with this string "<whitespace>The Brown bIg dOG".

I found the result is '<whitespace>The Brown BIg DOG'.

Is this the expected result or are you expecting 'The Brown Big Dog'?

Comment: @Amitava That's the expected result as it's only changing the first letter of each word if the letter of the word is lower case. In which it will change to upper case. I found error, if I input " p " it will return unchanged. Do you know what modifications i should make in order to fix this cause?

Comment: For the string "<whitespace>p<whitespace>"  use this :
          s = s.trim();
         char w = s.charAt(0); .......

Comment: @Amitava :S sadly we can't use trim.  As we haven't touched that yet.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to show you another solution:

```
private static String convertToTitleCase(String s)
{
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\s)[a-z]").matcher(s);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        builder.replace(m.start(), m.start() + 1, m.group().toUpperCase());
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

This uses a regular expression to find all the lowercase characters that are after a whitespace. Then using a loop and a string builder, it replaces all the lowercase letters found with uppercase ones.

Comment: I did the modifications and it still returns "<whitespace>p<whitespace> " and i found another problem. if i input "<whitespace>p" it will return "<whitespace> "

Comment: @ZackColbin Yeah I just realised that as well, I changed my answer to show another solution.